# How to fix 'Can't perform a React state...' error in React

Tags: reactjs

I making mutation in [LyricCreate](https://github.com/Antoskin/lyric/blob/client/client/src/components/Lyric/LyricCreate.js)

```
` onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { content } = this.state;
    const { songId, addLyric } = this.props;

    addLyric({
        variables: {
            content,
            songId
        },
    }).then( () => this.setState({ content: '' }) )
}`
```

it's going well, and adds to database.

### But in parent component appears error with [image]

after refresh page created Lyric appears in [lyricList](https://github.com/Antoskin/lyric/blob/client/client/src/components/Lyric/LyricList.js), and parent component [songDetails](https://github.com/Antoskin/lyric/blob/client/client/src/components/SongDetails.js) doesn't has errors till I make mutation again.

---

Help please..

Comment: you need to check if your component is still mounted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check if your component is mounted like this

```
componentDidMount() { 
  this._ismounted = true;
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   this._ismounted = false;
}

onSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const { content } = this.state;
   const { songId, addLyric } = this.props;

   addLyric({
        variables: {
            content,
            songId
        },
    }).then(() => {
       if(this._ismounted {
         this.setState({ content: '' }) 
       }
    })
}
```

Comment: Maybe u can help with another one question ?  When I make mutation after it query doesn't exists in network. And again after reload all fixings